# Google Glass setText() not working

Tags: android, textview, google-glass

I have a google glass application. It receives data from a mobile device via BT (but that shouldn't matter), in my app a handler is called to show that receiving data on the glass UI. I am using an activity on glass.

```
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) 
{
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
{
    switch(msg.what)
    {
    case 1:
        if(msg.arg2 == 1)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "got argument 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mMyTextView.setText("got argument 1");

        }
        else if(msg.arg2 == 2)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "got argument 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mMyTextView.setText("got argument 2");

        }
        break;
    default:
        // don't care about other cases, only case 1 is important
    }
}
```

};

mMyTextView is a member variable in my activity I fill in onCreate(), filling it in my handler doesn't make a difference.

Once I push my app from Eclipse to glass and run it, it works absolutely fine. Now on glass I swipe down, I don't handle this swipe event so onGesture returns simply false. Just in case it matters.

Now I am on the "ok glass" screen and via voice command I start my app. The toasts are shown as they should, but the text Views don't get updated anymore. Having breakpoints in my handler I can see that everything is filled correctly, the textView is not null, it shows in the textView's member variables the right text. the right text just doesn't appear on the UI. Publishing it again from Eclipse, starting it via voice command, and everything works fine again.

Comment: This is just a guess, but try assigning the TextView member available again in onResume.  Even though you see a non-null reference while debugging (good technique btw), maybe those references aren't valid anymore.  Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: I took the time in ms (to have a dynamic text) in onResume and displayed it on the very same text view. That works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue downloading an example from internet, i forgot adding in `onCreate()` method the reference of the `TextView` into the .xml layout;

```
private TextView mMyTextView;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
mMyTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mMyTextView);
...
...
...
```

Comment: I have setContentView in onCreate and mMyTextView find in onResume. Remmeber it all works on the first execution after install. So it might has to do somehow with the lifecycle manangement.